# React Hooks useState useEffect slideshow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I am trying to make a slideshow app by passing the following data to `Slide.js` via props.

```
const SLIDES = [
    {
        title: "Today's workout plan",
        text: "We're gonna do 3 fundamental exercises."
    },
    {
        title: "First, 10 push-ups",
        text: "Do 10 reps. Remember about full range of motion. Don't rush."
    },
    {
        title: "Next, 20 squats",
        text: "Squats are important. Remember to keep your back straight."
    },
    {
        title: "Finally, 15 sit-ups",
        text: "Slightly bend your knees. Remember about full range of motion."
    },
    {
        title: "Great job!",
        text: "You made it, have a nice day and see you next time!"
    }
];
```

My child component `Slide.js` has the following code

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function Slides({ slides }) {
  const [slideShow, setSlide] = useState(slides);

  useEffect(() => {
    setSlide(slideShow[0]);
    console.log("slides", slideShow[0]);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="navigation" className="text-center">
        <button data-testid="button-restart" className="small outlined">
          Restart
        </button>
        <button data-testid="button-prev" className="small">
          Prev
        </button>
        <button data-testid="button-next" className="small">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
      {slideShow.map((slide, i) => (
        <div id={i} className="card text-center">
          <h1 data-testid="title">{slide.title}</h1>
          <p data-testid="text">{slide.text}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Slides;
```

I thought using `setSlide(slideShow[0])` would only render the first item in the array of objects after the app initially loads. But I get

```
TypeError: slideShow.map is not a function
```

But when I `console.log("slides", slideShow[0])` I output

```
slides {title: "Today's workout plan", text: "We're gonna do 3 fundamental exercises."}
```

And if I change my code to

```
setSlide(slideShow.slice(0, 1));
```

The app shows only the first object in the array but if I `console.log("slides", slideShow)`, I get the whole array of objects even though I thought I should receive the sliced version.

Is my `map` function not referencing the `slideShow[0]` for the error to occur?

Comment: When you `setSlide(slideShow[0])` your `slideShow` is no longer an array that can be mapped over, it's an object. In the code you've given us, there's no reason to have the `useEffect` (or `useState`) hooks at all

Comment: State changes in React are asynchronous. You cannot `console.log` on the next line and see the change. Log the state in the main body of the function

Comment: *Is my map function not referencing the slideShow[0] for the error to occur?*, Yes. In `useEffect` you are doing `setSlide(slideShow[0])`which will be an object. So instead of `setSlide(slideShow[0])` this if you do `setSlide([{...slideShow[0]}])`, then it'll not break the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem over here is `setSlide(slideShow[0])`. Initially the state is initialised with an array called `slides`. But in the `useEffect` that state is being updated with an object. So, now the `slideShow` is no more an `array` but an `object`. Hence `object.map` is breaking the app.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    setSlide(slideShow[0]);
    console.log("slides", slideShow[0]);
  }, []);
```

Below is an example of the kind of operations which you are looking for. Instead of storing the `slides` in the state I just added `index` of the item in the `state` and updating it accordingly.

```js
const SLIDES = [{title:"Today's workout plan",text:"We're gonna do 3 fundamental exercises."},{title:"First, 10 push-ups",text:"Do 10 reps. Remember about full range of motion. Don't rush."},{title:"Next, 20 squats",text:"Squats are important. Remember to keep your back straight."},{title:"Finally, 15 sit-ups",text:"Slightly bend your knees. Remember about full range of motion."},{title:"Great job!",text:"You made it, have a nice day and see you next time!"}];

const { useState, useEffect } = React;

function Slides({ slides }) {
  const [selectedIndex, setSelectedIndex] = useState(0);

  const previous = () => {
    if(selectedIndex !== 0) {
      setSelectedIndex(index => index-1);
    }
  }
  
  const next = () => {
    if(selectedIndex !== slides.length - 1) {
      setSelectedIndex(index => index+1);
    }
  }
  
  const restart = () => {
    setSelectedIndex(0);
  }
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div id="navigation" className="text-center">
        <button data-testid="button-restart" className="small outlined" onClick={restart}>
          Restart
        </button>
        <button data-testid="button-prev" className="small" onClick={previous}>
          Prev
        </button>
        <button data-testid="button-next" className="small" onClick={next}>
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
      <div className="card text-center">
        <h1 data-testid="title">{slides[selectedIndex].title}</h1>
        <p data-testid="text">{slides[selectedIndex].text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Slides slides={SLIDES}/>, document.getElementById("react"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>


<div id="react"></div>
```

Note: Here, for all the three operations we can just have one single function, just for simplicity I have created three different functions for updating the slide index.

Answer (score 1):

The error is referencing this line `slideShow.map((slide, i) => (`

The problem is that your useEffect is called after your component renders, and you set slideshow to be a single slide `slideShow[0]`. You then proceed to re-render your component, and you try to map over slideShow, but slideshow is equal to the first item of your original slideshow variable (`slideshow[0]`) and you can't map over a single slide.

---

You would probably want to edit your code to be something more like

```
function Slides({ slides }) {
  const [slideIdx, setSlide] = useState(0);

  const updateIndex = (val) => {
      if (val === -1){
          if (slideIdx === 0){
              setSlide(slides.length -1)
          }else{
              setSlide(slideIdx - 1)
          }
      }
      if (val === 1){
          if (slideIdx === slides.length - 1){
              setSlide(0)
          }else{
              setSlide(slideIdx + 1)
          }
      }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div id="navigation" className="text-center">
        <button onClick={() => setSlide(0)} data-testid="button-restart" className="small outlined">
          Restart
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => updateIndex(-1)} data-testid="button-prev" className="small">
          Prev
        </button>
        <button onClick={() => updateIndex(1)} data-testid="button-next" className="small">
          Next
        </button>
      </div>
        <div id="Whatyouwant" className="card text-center">
          <h1 data-testid="title">{slides[slideIdx].title}</h1>
          <p data-testid="text">{slides[slideIdx].text}</p>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

[Here's an answer where I tried to implement something similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63801654/6331353)

Comment: I tried implementing your solution but I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined`

Comment: @ElijahLee I updated some stuff. It's probably not an exact solution, you'll probably have to work with it a bit

Answer (score 0):

useState is async by nature but doesn't return a promise, but to solve the asynchronous nature of useState and a quick dirty fix would be to just put a null propagation on your data e.g.

slideshow?.map

but how I would do it would be something like this:
Just throwing some ideas for you

```
import SLIDES from ....slides.etc

const [slideIndex, setSlideIndex]=useState(0)

<item onClick={()=>{setSlideIndex(slideIndex + 1)}} >
{SLIDES[slideIndex]}
</item>
```

just an example to give you an idea